# Differential Forms on a complex manifold

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, differential-topology, tensor-products, complex-geometry

Given a complex manifold $M$, we can complexify its wedge product of tangent cotangent bundles. Consider $\wedge^{k}T^{\ast}M \otimes \mathbb C$, and we know that $T^{\ast}M \otimes \mathbb C$ decomposes into $T^{\ast}M^{(1,0)} \oplus T^{\ast}M^{(0,1)}$.

Then by the commutativity of wedge product and direcsum, we conclude that $\wedge^{k}T^{\ast}M = \bigoplus_{p+q = k} \wedge^{p}T^{\ast}M^{(1,0)} \otimes \wedge^{q}T^{\ast}M^{(0,1)}$.

A $(p,q)$ form is  a section of $\wedge^{p}T^{\ast}M^{(1,0)} \otimes \wedge^{q}T^{\ast}M^{(0,1)}$, but why does a typical element of (p,q) form looks like $dz_{k_1} \wedge dz_{k_p} \ldots \wedge d\bar{z_{t_1}} \ldots \wedge d \bar{z_{t_1}}$ in local coordinates? Where does the tensor product go?

Answer (score 2):

You wrote:$$\Lambda^{k}T^{\ast}M = \bigoplus_{p+q = k} \Lambda^{p}{(T^{1,0})}^*M \otimes \Lambda^{q}{(T^{0,1})}^*M$$

This is wrong, the correct identity is
$$(\Lambda^{k}T^{\ast}M)\otimes \mathbb{C} = \bigoplus_{p+q = k} \Lambda^{p}{(T^{1,0})}^*M \wedge \Lambda^{q}{(T^{0,1})}^*M$$

You derive this identity like so:
$$\begin{align}
(\Lambda^{k}T^*M) \otimes \mathbb{C} &= \Lambda^{k} (T^*M \otimes \mathbb{C})\\
& = \Lambda^{k} ({(T^{1,0})}^*M \oplus {(T^{0,1})}^*M)\\
&= \bigoplus_{p+q = k} \Lambda^{p}{(T^{1,0})}^*M \wedge \Lambda^{q}{(T^{0,1})}^*M
\end{align}
$$
The tensor product didn't go anywhere because it wasn't there to begin with: it was already gone as soon as you wrote $T^*M \otimes \mathbb{C} = {(T^{1,0})}^*M \oplus {(T^{0,1})}^*M$.

---

EDIT:
As TedShifrin points out in the comment, most texts write a tensor product (as you did) instead of a wedge there. I suppose that in general $V \wedge W$ does not make sense when $V$ and $W$ are different vector spaces but $V \otimes W$ does, which probably explains the choice of "most texts". But they're wrong: $dz \otimes d\bar{z}$ is not the same as $dz \wedge d\bar{z}$. The point is that $dz \wedge d\bar{z}$ does make sense, because $dz$ and $d\bar{z}$ are both one-forms (complexified). More generally, $\Lambda^{p}{(T^{1,0})}^*M$ and $\Lambda^{q}{(T^{0,1})}^*M$ are not the same vector space but they are both subspaces of the complexified exterior algebra $(\Lambda T^*M) \otimes \mathbb{C}$, so their wedge product is a well-defined subspace of $(\Lambda T^*M) \otimes \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Seub, that may be, but most texts write the tensor product there, not the wedge, the understanding being that one descends to the skew-symmetric version (or applies Alt).

Comment: @TedShifrin Good point. I edited my answer to address this, let me know if you agree.

Comment: I see. To prove like how you did it, we probably want the two vector spaces to be the subspaces of a larger space. Otherwise it does not make sense to "add" them directly, since for different vector spaces we want to use tuples for the direct sum. Is that the reason for the tensor product rather than it does not make sense to wedge two different spaces?

Answer (score 0):

From the identity $T^{\ast}M\otimes \mathbb{C} = T^{\ast}M^{(1,0)} \oplus T^{\ast}M^{(0,1)}$ and with fixed local frames $\{dz_1 , \dots, dz_n \}$ and $\{d\bar z_1 , \dots, d\bar z_n \}$ for $T^{\ast}M^{(1,0)}$ and $T^{\ast}M^{(0,1)}$ respectively, we can construct the bundle
$$
\bigwedge^\ast (T^{\ast}M\otimes \mathbb{C})
$$
wich is has a frame given by the wedge products of $\{dz_1 , \dots, dz_n, d\bar z_1 , \dots, d\bar z_n \}$.

Here no tensor product will apear when you pick an element of type $(p,q)$.

The formula for the exterior power of a direct sum
$$
\wedge^{k}(T^{\ast}M\otimes \mathbb{C}) \, {\Huge \simeq} \bigoplus_{p+q = k} \wedge^{p}T^{\ast}M^{(1,0)} \otimes \wedge^{q}T^{\ast}M^{(0,1)}
$$
is correct. The missing thing is an identification. Here a $(p,q)$ form is a section 
$$
\eta =\sum\limits_{|I|=p, |J|=q} a_{IJ}dz_I\otimes d\bar z_{J} \in \Gamma( \wedge^{p}T^{\ast}M^{(1,0)} \otimes \wedge^{q}T^{\ast}M^{(0,1)})
$$
The identification is
$$ 
\eta \longmapsto \sum\limits_{|I|=p, |J|=q} a_{IJ}dz_I \wedge d\bar z_{J} \in \Gamma( \wedge^{p+q}(T^{\ast}M\otimes \mathbb{C})).
$$
Note that this is well defined and bijective (onto its image, $\wedge^{p,q}(T^{\ast}M\otimes \mathbb{C})$)  as you can arrange the terms so that the $dz_j$ come ahead of the $d\bar z_i$.